# Adding large quantities of HTML with Jquery/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, indentation, insertion

I'm working on a form that auto-generates a large addition when the user specifies, including a editable canvas, selectable inputs, textareas and so on. I'm wondering if there's a tool for appending large blocks of HTML more easily and with better style: for instance, in my codeigniter PHP views it's easily done just by closing the PHP tag and referencing variables using `<?=var?>`.

```
<?php if (condition) {?>
    <h1>List a variable <?=$var?></h1>
<?php }?>
```

Is the above terrible style? Is there a comparable tool to use for javascript so I can include html with proper indentation?

EDIT:
To be clearer, I'm not looking for a lot of input on the php - my objective is to make editing the HTML I'm inserting with javascript cleaner.
The problem is analogous to this:

```
    <?php
if (condition) {
echo "<div>";
echo "<p> a line of html code<p>";
echo "<h1> more stuff and a ".$variable;
echo "<div>";
}
?>

//vs

<?php 
if (condition) { ?>
<div>
    <p> A line of html code, but easier to edit</p>
    <h1> a <?=$var?>
</div>

<? } ?>
```

The second one is cleaner and easier to edit for the developer. So I'd like to do the same with javascript and take this:

```
$(this).append('<p>a whole bunch of stuff'+var+'more stuff<p>');
$(this).append('<p>more stuff<p>');
$(this).append('<h1>more stuff<h1>');
```

And make it easier to manage.

Comment: FYI php shorttags are not recommended. Really should change to `<?php echo $var; ?>`

Comment: Are they in danger of being deprecated? It's awfully convenient to write things like <?=base_url()?> for links rather than <?php echo base_url()?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#strings). It adds some features to normal javascript like string interpolation, block strings and stuff that makes writing huge blocks of HTML string literals a piece of cake.

Comment: This looks good - Just the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is for the DEVELOPER, to make source code maintainable and readable. It has nothing to do with making "view source" look nice.

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm trying to make my javascript source look nice, for me, the developer. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear - this would be so I could more easily work on the HTML I'm inserting with the javascript. On the other hand, though, clean source on the user end does make debugging easier if you use something like firebug.

Answer (score 1):

It does look a little unpleasant, certainly.

I'd probably write it like this, if I was using that particular approach to page generation.

```
<?php 
      if (condition)
         echo "<h1>List a variable $var</h1>";
?>
```

You may also like to look into the DOM methods of php. They can make creating reusable, modular code much easier. 
They're not as fast as simple string operations, but far neater and more powerful. When the daily traffic means this difference in speed is a problem you've probably got the money to throw at some ode monkey to make the required changes.